# How to use push in a java script loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

I am trying to write a code to do the following:

1. Check digits on a given 16 digit array from right to left.
2. Double every other digit as you iterate to left (the 16th digit is not doubled).
3. If the doubled number > 9 ; then subtract 9 from this number and push the number to the new array.
4. Return true if the sum of these new digits in the new array equal to a multiplier of 10, else return false.

I'm stuck on the step 3. Below is my code and I'm not sure why push function wouldn't to create a new array, can anyone help?

```
let validateCred = (Arr) =>
    for (let i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            validateCred.push((Arr[i] * 2) % 9)
        } else {
            validateCred.push(Arr[i])
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: `validateCred` is a function, not an array

Comment: *"... and came up with a new array including these new numbers"* Wha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complete function could be as follows:

```js
let validateCred = arr => {
  console.log("Original array:", "[" + arr .toString() + "]")
  let result = []
  for (let i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) result.push((arr[i] * 2) % 9)
    else result.push(arr[i])
  }
  console.log("Modified array:", "[" + result.toString() + "]")
  return result.reduce((a, b) => a + b) % 10 === 0
}

console.log("Array valid:", validateCred([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]))
```

Comment: one of the arrays given is as below and it is supposed return true although it returns false with above code when I put it in where the array is written manually. Does anyone know what I missing?                                                                                                                   const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6]

Comment: why it is supposed to return true?! 
the result of your `valid5` array is this
`[ 6, 3, 6, 0, 6, 7, 7, 3, 9, 8, 0, 8, 9, 6, 5, 8]`
and the sum is is `91` which is not dividable by 10 so `false` is the expected result
why the confusion?!

Answer (score 0):

```
let validateCred = (Arr) =>{
for (let i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        Arr.push((Arr[i] * 2) % 9)
    } else {
        Arr.push(Arr[i])
    };
}
return Arr };
```

I guess that's what you mean. In fact you need to write the name of the array followed by .push. And dont forget to return your array.
This is the documentation for further details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

```
validateCred = (Arr) => {
  let resArr = []; //resultant array to push to

  for (let i = Arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) { //every other (even indexed) item
      let doubled = Arr[i] * 2; //double every number
      if (doubled > 9) { //if doubled number is bigger than 9
        resArr.push(doubled - 9); //subtract 9 and push to resultant array
      }
    }
  }

  //You now have to iterate over the resultant array to find the sum
  let sum = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < resArr.length; j++) {
    sum += resArr[j];
  }

  (sum % 10 === 0) ? return true : return false;
}
```

Or you could do your entire program without the second array, if you're just looking for the sum of every other digit as you explain in your question. It would look like this:

```
validateCred = (Arr) => {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = Arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) { //every other (even indexed) item
      let doubled = Arr[i] * 2; //double every number
      if (doubled > 9) { //if doubled number is bigger than 9
        sum += (doubled - 9);
      }
    }
  }

  //check the sum
  (sum % 10 === 0) ? return true : return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why push function wouldn't to create a new array

The `push` method adds elements to an *existing* array. You need to explicitly create the array before yourself.

```
function validateCred(Arr) {
    const newArr = [];
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for (let i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            newArr.push((Arr[i] * 2) % 9)
        } else {
            newArr.push(Arr[i])
        };
    }
    … // use newArr
}
```

Comment: I plugged in an array to see what it will return but it only returns undefined. console.log(validateCred(valid5));     valid5 is a given array as following: const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

Comment: @BasakUlcay Step 4 of your task is still missing, that's what the `…` in my code is meant for. You need to write the part that actually `return`s something.